# Error "Build Failed Command "npm run build" exited with 1 - RollupError: Could not resolve" al realizar deploy con vercel con vite-react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, vercel

actualmente terminé un projecto que hice para un curso de react js y estoy teniendo inconvenientes a la hora de realizar el deploy en vercel. Intenté cambiar la forma de importar los componentes, les cambié el nombre y nada aún funciona.

Según logro entender el problema es con un archivo js que utilizo para realizar el routing de mi aplicación (estoy utilizando react router) en conjunto con un componente en especifico. También he revisado en la app si me daba algún error en consola y todo parece funcionar bien. Desconozco si es una cuestión de la versión de node (18.16.0 y actualmente está la 18.17.1) o vercel en si mismo.

Aquí adjunto el código primero del error de vercel y luego del archivo en cuestion con la configuración del routing:

ERROR VERCEL:

```
[20:37:39.098] Running build in San Francisco, USA (West) – sfo1
[20:37:39.221] Cloning github.com/ezequielquevedo111/react-ecommerce-eq (Branch: main, Commit: ce94de8)
[20:37:39.354] Previous build cache not available
[20:37:40.636] Cloning completed: 1.414s
[20:37:40.985] Running "vercel build"
[20:37:41.491] Vercel CLI 32.1.0
[20:37:42.048] Installing dependencies...
[20:37:46.536] npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[20:37:46.994] npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
[20:37:47.028] npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[20:37:47.109] npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[20:37:49.915] npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
[20:38:02.132] 
[20:38:02.132] added 1324 packages in 20s
[20:38:02.132] 
[20:38:02.132] 120 packages are looking for funding
[20:38:02.132]   run `npm fund` for details
[20:38:02.167] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[20:38:02.167] Running "npm run build"
[20:38:02.475] 
[20:38:02.475] > react-project-ecommerce@0.0.0 build
[20:38:02.475] > vite build
[20:38:02.475] 
[20:38:02.897] [36mvite v4.3.9 [32mbuilding for production...[36m[39m
[20:38:02.932] transforming...
[20:38:03.620] [32m✓[39m 91 modules transformed.
[20:38:03.620] [32m✓ built in 722ms[39m
[20:38:03.620] [31mCould not resolve "../components/pages/ItemListContainer/ItemListContainer.jsx" from "src/routes/routes.js"[39m
[20:38:03.620] file: [36m/vercel/path0/src/routes/routes.js[39m
[20:38:03.622] [31merror during build:
[20:38:03.622] RollupError: Could not resolve "../components/pages/ItemListContainer/ItemListContainer.jsx" from "src/routes/routes.js"
[20:38:03.623]     at error (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2130:30)
[20:38:03.623]     at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24041:24)
[20:38:03.623]     at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24003:26[39m
[20:38:03.649] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

ARCHIVO JS:

```
import ItemListContainer from "../components/pages/ItemListContainer/ItemListContainer.jsx";
import ItemDetailContainer from "../components/pages/ItemDetailContainer/ItemDetailContainer.jsx";
import CartContainer from "../components/pages/Cart/CartContainer.jsx";
import CheckoutContainer from "../components/pages/Checkout/CheckoutContainer.jsx";

export const routesArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    path: "/",
    Element: ItemListContainer,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    path: "/categoryProduct/:category",
    Element: ItemListContainer,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    path: "/itemDetail/:id",
    Element: ItemDetailContainer,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    path: "/cart",
    Element: CartContainer,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    path: "/checkout",
    Element: CheckoutContainer,
  },
];
```

ROUTING CON REACT ROUTER:

```
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import AppRouter from "./routes/AppRouter";
import CartGlobalContextProvider from "./context/CartGlobalContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <CartGlobalContextProvider>
          <AppRouter />
        </CartGlobalContextProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "../components/layout/Layout";
import SaveErrorPage from "./SaveErrorPage";
import { routesArray } from "./routes.js";

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
        {routesArray.map(({ id, path, Element }) => (
          <Route key={id} path={path} element={<Element />} />
        ))}
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<SaveErrorPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!
Adjunto además link del repo de github: https://github.com/ezequielquevedo111/react-ecommerce-eq.git

Comment: Hola Eze, bienvenido, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos, 
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.